# CSS transition slide right

Tags: css, css-transitions

I need to add a CSS transition to this code to have the button's width changes smoothly on hover, but I can't make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeyKosov/fa9c6nfc/1/

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
    <span class="caption">Button text</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn .caption {
    display: none;
}
.btn:hover .caption {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: since display doesn't have a 'middle' value, you'll have to restrucutre your css slighly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `max-width` for this.

```
.btn .caption {
    max-width: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
.btn:hover .caption {
    max-width: 999px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fa9c6nfc/2/

Comment: Thanks, it works great, especially if add "vertical-align: top" to .caption